# Alarm broadcaster, pass object or pass id and pull object from sqlite?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-sqlite

I need your recommendation on something. In a  nutshell, I am setting up an alarm (task reminder kind of app) in which upon expiry, the broadcaster puts a notification with the task info in the notification bar. The task information are storied in 2 objects.

Should I:
1) put the task info in an intent (serialized) in which I would pull it up upon alarm expiry from the passed in intent and display the relevent info?

2) Don't pass the two objects in the intent,  just pass an ID, and upon expiry I would pull the two object from my SQL lite db to display them?

which one is more efficient, better way to do it?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just pass the id.  That will save you a lot of trouble with serialization and deserialization.

Comment: Please keep in mind that I have object already implementing serialization and being passed around between activities do you still recommend above in this case?

Comment: Accepted given its the only answer

Comment: If the object ever changes you'd need to redo both sides of the serialization.  Passing the ID is just a cleaner solution.